# object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-swagger

Olá!

I dont have any idea whats happen with my "/" where direct to my swagger.
Was working normally, but appear this problem right now:

```
Traceback:  

File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  477.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  437.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/guilherme/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in raise_uncaught_exception
  448.         raise exc

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: 'Link' object does not support item assignment
Request information:
GET: No GET data
```

Anyone have idea whats happen?

Tks

(sorry for my terrible english)

Comment: Try looking in the web server error log for a more detailed error message.

Comment: As a side comment, does anyone know why Django insists on displaying near-useless tracebacks such as this one that don't include the line of _your_ code that caused the exception?

Comment: In this case, the error is being generated from within Django Rest Framework. The code likely isn't happening _in_ his code. This makes sense, given how working with an API framework typically unfolds.